# How to change my server side use of ASP:ImageButton to HTML img tag only

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, image, imagebutton

I am trying to wire some fancy Javascript (PopBox) to an ImageButton control and I am getting a very strange run-time (Compilation) error.

```
<asp:imagebutton id="imgBtnPicture" runat="server" 
      class="PopBoxImageSmall"
      pbshowcaption="true"
      title="Click to magnify/shrink"
      onclick="Pop(this,50,'PopBoxImageLarge');"
      width="90%">
  </asp:imagebutton>
```

I've looked at replacing the ImageButton web control with a simpler HTML img tag (which is what the PopBox documentation suggests).

Yet, I don't know how to populate an `<img>` tag from the CodeBehind file. Here is a typical statement which sets the .SRC property from an ASP.Net dataset row:

```
    Me.imgBtnPicture.Src = theRow.Item("ImageURL")
```

I've tried this as an alternative:

```
<img alt="" src="" 
   id="imgPicture" runat="server"class="PopBoxImageSmall" title="Click to magnify/shrink"        
   onclick="Pop(this,50,'PopBoxImageLarge');" width="90%"
/>
```

Visual Studio 2008 does not complain about this declaration above but in the codebehind file, how would I address this so I could populate the .Src attribute.

Intellisense, cannot even "see" this

```
 Me.imgPicture.src = theUrl    'this won't compile...
```

I added this at the top of the codebehind but seemed to have no effect:

```
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
```

Comment: Can you not populate the image url directly in the HTML in the src attribute? is it dynamic? <img alt="" src=""....

Comment: yeah i cant see what's dynamic about it - therefore it shouldnt even be a server-side image. you could always use `src='<%= GetImageSrc() =>'` to get the src (as opposed to making it server-side, and setting the .Src attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<asp:imagebutton onclick="..." >` is for a server method (code behide).

try with onclientclick

Answer (score 1):

in asp.net imagebutton there is no property class change it to cssclass="PopBoxImageSmall"

then it will work.

Comment: Thanks to y34h and Moksha. All I really did was change to onclientclick and cssclass keeping the context of the <asp:ImageButton> as it was. I still don't see how to dynamically construct the HTML content from the codebehind for a standard <img> tag but the web control for ImageButton is now working with this fancy Javascript so I will settle for that and move forward for now. @Nick, in the .aspx.vb codebehind file, Me.imgPicture.Src (where imgPicture is based on <img id="imgPicture"...etc.) cannot compile because imgPicture is not a member of the namespace.class). It'there, but how to set?

Answer (score 0):

It's case sensitive, make sure you're still setting the `Src` property, capital `S`...and just remove the `src=""` from the tag itself so there's no confusion by anyone reading it later:

```
Me.imgPicture.Src = theUrl
```

Comment: Nick, please note that I have used the case sensitive syntax in the codebehind file - namely, Me.imgPicture.Src = theUrl but the problem is that the compiler cannot "see" this: I get this during the build:

Comment: error BC30456: 'imgPicture' is not a member of 'Zipeee.frmDisplayAd'.

Comment: @John - is the image wrapped in another control, another naming container?